# How to change hotkey of switch language in windows with outo hotkey script?

Tags: windows-8, hotkeys

I want when press `menu` key of keyboard input language changed. Windows OS has not  setting for do this.I can change language by 
`~LAlt & e::Send ^{Shift}`  script but this difficult I want do this with Ctrl key only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change the menu key behavior.

However, you can do this:

Control Panel | Region and Language
Keyboards and Languages tab
Click Change Keyboards
Advanced Key Settings tab

There you can set the shortcut combination that selects each language.
Or if you only have a few languages installed, Left ALT + SHIFT will switch between/among them.

Comment: I can change language by Left ALT + SHIFT but I need  to change language by menu key.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  The menu key just brings up the rightclick menu of whatever program you're working in.  The program itself decides what it'll show you there.

Comment: Please see this : http://superuser.com/questions/239963/hotkey-to-switch-input-language-in-windows-7?rq=1